# mod_rewrite: How can I rewrite a url with slash?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I can rewrite `mydomain.com`to `www.mydomain.com`, that's OK.

But, I just couldn't figure how to rewrite:

`http://mydomain.com/great-article` to `http://www.mydomain.com/great-article`.

How can this be done with regex? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: great-articel is page or a subdirectory, if it's a page you need to write the rule to hide extension as well as the slash based url.

Answer (score 4):

This shall work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule .*             http://www.mydomain.com/$0 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

I.e. every request to
`http://mydomain.com/something`
will get redirected to
`http://www.mydomain.com/something`.

As well as simple requests
`http://mydomain.com/`
will go to
`http://www.mydomain.com/`.

And due to **Query string append (QSA)** - this shall work for such URI
`http://mydomain.com/index.php?action=hello&param=world`
to get redirected to
`http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?action=hello&param=world`.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: So the answer to my original question, thanks to justasb, for a Magento installation it worked like this :

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$
    RewriteRule .* http://www.mydomain.com/$0 [L,R=301,QSA]
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: @user1085605 please mark the answer as correct (the check hook left of the question)